# Bind inner scope variables to outer "template"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a transclusive directive in AngularJS which has its own isolated scope. The scope contains transclusiveDirectiveScopeVariable.

```
myApp.directive('MyTransclusiveDirective', function () {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            transcluseDirectiveScopeVariable: '='
        },
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.transclusiveDirectiveScopeVariable = Math.random();
        },
        template: '<div class="fancy"><ng-transclude></ngtransclude></div>'
    };
);
```

})

I would like to use the scope variable in the "outer template" of the directive - the part that replaces ng-transclusive in the template.

Here is what I expect:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
    <my-transclusive-directive>
        <p>The first fancy random number is {{transclusiveDirectiveScopeVariable"}}!</p>
    </my-transclusive-directive>

    <my-transclusive-directive>
        <p>The second fancy random number is {{transclusiveDirectiveScopeVariable"}}!</p>
    </my-transclusive-directive>
</div>
```

should give me two different fancy numbers. This approach does not work (because here we are binding to the scope of the Controller).

Answer 1 suggests to introduce additional variables in the Controller's scope and to bind them one- or two-directional to the directive's scope variable. If nothing else works this could be a workaround. But then I have trouble if I want to bind the variable in the  part of the directive:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
    <my-transclusive-directive transclusiveDirectiveScopeVariable="x">
        <input type="text" ng-model="x" />
    </my-transclusive-directive>
</div>
```

What would be the correct approach to that problem?

Comment: Can you give a better description to your question ?

Comment: I've added some more code, hope it makes it more clear

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1 (one way binding)

In Your return part of your directive:

```
scope: { 
  ScopeTobeAccessedFromOutside: '@',
}
```

In your directive implementation

```
<my-transclusive-directive scope-tobe-accessed-from-outside="{{ anyScopeName }}">
</my-transclusive-directive>
<!--- you can access the scope from outside now -->
{{anyScopeName}}
```

### Option 2 (2 way binding)

In Your return part of your directive:

```
scope: { 
  ScopeTobeAccessedFromOutside: '=',
}
```

In your directive implementation

```
<my-transclusive-directive scope-tobe-accessed-from-outside="anyScopeName">
</my-transclusive-directive>
<!--- you can access the scope from outside now -->
{{anyScopeName}}
```